# Upgrade to VS2010: Random Unresolved Symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, upgrade, symbols

I just went from visual studio 2008 to 2010, and after solving all issues my project runs perfectly.

However sometimes a project is complaining about unresolved symbols. When I rebuild the objects causing the issues the problem is solved again, at least until I edit and compile part of the project again.

The solution contains the Lua project and compiles it as dll. A game engine project uses Lua, and the game project also does this so it can register necessary game-functions. The game project also links to the game engine project of course.

It's always the game project being unable to resolve Lua project symbols.

References and dependencies are set correctly as far as I can see.

Thanks

Comment: can you post your project to sourceforge or similar, so we can have a look?

Comment: With VS 2005 we sometimes see spurious (~? 1:100) linker errors wrt unresolved symbols. Never reproducible. Can you quantify your "sometimes"?

Comment: It seems to happen after I edit any part of the game project and compile it. When I recompile the problematic objects the symbols resolve just fine once more.

The problem does not occur in the engine project at all, even though it links to the Lua project in the same manner as the game project.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch:

Are you using the "minimal rebuild" flag? That one has seldom worked well for me, as it seems to depend on your project/includes being set up in some unknown, mysterious way. ;)

Something might've changed going into VS2010 that breaks these assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something on your system is corrupting (perhaps truncating) the static import library.  Take a good close look at your antivirus.

Another possibility is a build step that modifies an existing file instead of creating a new one (e.g. using the librarian to add objects to a static library).  In this case when the DLL is recompiled, the static import library is recreated without the objects, but has a newer timestamp and doesn't trigger a rebuild.  The solution is to use a different name for the merged library than the static import library used to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's related, but VS2010 started showing intellisense errors for C++ in it's error output window.  Especially in x64 builds, I have seen a lot of lot of these that are actually coming out of the system header files.  My projects still compile and run flawlessly.  Are these intellisense errors or build errors?